# Fuzzy match column headers for many data.frames with same number of columns?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr, fuzzy-search

I have ~6000 data.frames with the same number of columns, but human-labelled headers, meaning there are things like typos, and occasionally an extra word (e.g. what should be `address` could appear as `street_address`).

Note that all the column names are fairly distinct (the closest are `first_name` and `last_name`), but all the others have no overlap in words

Is there an established 'best practice' for matching the column headers so that they can be organised into one single dataframe?

What I guess so far is to simply match the columns by the number of characters that match (e.g. `street_address` would probably match correctly to `address` since 7 characters match)

Is there a better / more established / more reliable way?

Note: I can use either R (preferably dplyr), or python (e.g. pandas) for this (as well as any other libraries in either language)

Comment: How many columns across the 6k dfs? Are columns in the same order? Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: @Matt i should have mentioned, the columns are not in the same order

Comment: @Matt 30 columns per dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a got at it...

**sample data**

```
df1 <- data.frame( first.name = c( "bobby", "carl" ),
                   last_name = c( "fisscher", "sagan") )
df2 <- data.frame( lst_name = c("ice","cream"),
                   frst_name = c("ben","jerry") )
df3 <- data.frame( first_nam = c("bert", "ernie"),
                   last_nam = c("elmo", "oscar"))


df1;df2;df3 

# first.name last_name
# 1      bobby  fisscher
# 2       carl     sagan

# lst_name frst_name
# 1      ice       ben
# 2    cream     jerry

# first_nam last_nam
# 1      bert     elmo
# 2     ernie    oscar
```

**code**

```
library( stringdist )
library( data.table )

#add all data.frames to a list
L <- list(df1,df2,df3)

#reorder the df's, based on the stringdistance from 
#  the columnnames of df_n with those of df1
data.table::rbindlist(
  lapply( L, function(x) {
    #get stringdistance matrix of colnames
    temp <- stringdistmatrix( names(df1), names(x), useNames = TRUE )
    #get the colname of x that matches the one of df1 closest
    colOrder <- colnames(x)[apply(temp,1,which.min)]
    #reorder x accordingly
    x[, colOrder ]
  }),
  #rowbind, ignoring the columnnames, the order is all that matters
  use.names = FALSE )

#    first.name last_name
# 1:      bobby  fisscher
# 2:       carl     sagan
# 3:        ben       ice
# 4:      jerry     cream
# 5:       bert      elmo
# 6:      ernie     oscar
```